# uwp gridview delete item with button within datatemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, mvvm, uwp-xaml

I have a **gridview in UWP app** and I have put a **button** in each gridview item in **datatemplate** so that it can be used to **delete/remove** that specific item from the gridview ( removing it from **observableCollection** behind). I am not using **MVVM** approach, because I am not much familiar with it, I am using a normal Observable Collection for binding of data and data template.

if you can suggest me a better way to do it, myabe using MVVM please suggest me how to do it. **Thanks in advance**

**Code :**

**XAML GRID VIEW** (button with the red back ground is the button I wanna use to delete item)

```
<controls:AdaptiveGridView Name="HistoryGridView" StretchContentForSingleRow="False"
                           Style="{StaticResource MainGridView}"
                           ItemClick ="HistoryGridView_SelectionChanged"
                           ItemsSource="{x:Bind HistoryVideos, Mode=OneWay}">
    <controls:AdaptiveGridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate  x:DataType="data:Video">
            <StackPanel Margin="4" >
                <Grid>
                    <Button  Background="Red"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                            Height="36" Canvas.ZIndex="1"
                            Style="{StaticResource TransparentButton}" Width="36">
                        <fa:FontAwesome Icon="Close" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"
                                            />
                    </Button>
                    <Image  Canvas.ZIndex="0"    Source="{x:Bind Thumbnail}" Style="{StaticResource GridViewImage}"/>
                    <Border Style="{StaticResource TimeBorder}" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                            Canvas.ZIndex="1"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Duration}" Foreground="White" Height="Auto"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}"  Style="{StaticResource GridViewVideoName}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ParentName}"  Style="{StaticResource GridViewParentName}"/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Views}" Style="{StaticResource GridViewViews}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Views" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>

        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:AdaptiveGridView.ItemTemplate>
</controls:AdaptiveGridView>
```

**Code Behind**

```
public History()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    HistoryVideos = new ObservableCollection<Video>();
}

public ObservableCollection<Video> HistoryVideos { get; private set; }
```

> I am using onnavigated to method for filling the collection and it works fine and also I guess that is not relevent here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can add the `Command` to the `Button` to invoke when this button is pressed and we can use parameter to pass to the Command property.

To use the Command, we should be able to define a `DelegateCommand` class that inherits from the [`ICommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.input.icommand).

For example:

```
internal class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> execute;
    private Func<object, bool> canExecute;

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute)
    {
        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = (x) => { return true; };
    }

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute)
    {
        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
        {
            CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

We can add the `Id` property in the `Video`, then we can pass the `Id` property to the `CommandParameter`. When we click the `Button`, the `ExecuteDeleteCommand` method will be fired. We can use the `Id` to find the `Video` in the `HistoryVideos` and use the `Remove` method to remove it.

The ViewModel code：

```
internal class ViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<Viedo> _videos;

    public ObservableCollection<Viedo> Videos
    {
        get
        {
            return _videos;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_videos != value)
            {
                _videos = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public ICommand DeleteCommand { set; get; }

    private void ExecuteDeleteCommand(object param)
    {
        int id = (Int32)param;
        Viedo cus = GetCustomerById(id);

        if (cus != null)
        {
            Videos.Remove(cus);
        }
    }

    private Viedo GetCustomerById(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            return Videos.First(x => x.Id == id);
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Videos = new ObservableCollection<Viedo>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Videos.Add(new Viedo());
            Videos[i].Name = "Name";
            Videos[i].Id = i;
        }

        this.DeleteCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteDeleteCommand);
    }
}
```

The XAML code：

```
<GridView Name="MyGridView"  ItemsSource="{Binding Videos}">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                <Button  Background="Red"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Height="36" Canvas.ZIndex="1"
                Width="36"  Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteCommand, ElementName=MyGridView}" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}">
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

The code behind:

```
private ViewModel myViewModel;

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    myViewModel = new ViewModel();
    MyGridView.DataContext = myViewModel;
}
```

Update:

```
<GridView Name="MyGridView"  ItemsSource="{x:Bind myViewModel.Videos}">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Viedo">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}"></TextBlock>
                <Button  Background="Red"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Height="36" Canvas.ZIndex="1"
                Width="36"  Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteCommand, ElementName=MyGridView}" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}">
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Comment: can I ask why are we using Inotifyproeprtty changed . doesnt an Observable Collection has that feature built in already ?

Comment: @touseef Yes, you are right, I have updated the answer.  The `ObservableCollection` provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.

Comment: thnku and it looks like a good answer. but I have been researching and I guess it can be done with x:Bind as well which is more performant. And also we dont need ICommand implementation in that case? is that right? If  so can you please suggest an implementation that way as well? :)

Comment: My solution is  using MVVM approach, we also can use the x:bind. If we use the `Command` and `CommandParameter`, we need the ICommand implementation. Due to the `DeleteCommand` is not in the Video class, that we can not use the x:bind for the `Command` of the `Button`. If you want to use, you should be able to set the `DeleteCommand`  in the `Video` class.